# How can i setting wsdl service in flex project crossdomain.xml

Tags: apache-flex, security, wsdl, crossdomain.xml

H**ow can i settings crossdomain.xml my flex project.** this is my *crossdomain.xml.*

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
   <cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
 </cross-domain-policy>
```

I've tried lots of different methods but my project send error message "**Security error accessing url
Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (http://78.189.......wsdl**"

put the file in different places
  C:\wamp\www\MYPROJECT\bin-debug\crossdomain.xml 
      (my swf url : http://localhost/bin-debug/test.html checked http://localhost/bin-debug/crossdomain.xml its ok)
  C:\wamp\www\crossdomain.xml

I added the load line of the project

```
            protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost/MYPROJECT/bin-debug/crossdomain.xml");

            }
```

if flex server type select none everythings ok. but server type select PHP need crossdomain.xml 
 **how can i fix**

Comment: if the swf is not in the same domain you need to put the master crossdomain.xml in the domain that the swf is contacting

Comment: yes my master crossdomain.xml file location is c:\wamp\www\crossdomain.xml  this { 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy> }

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem myself.**

crossdomain.xml file must be inside to webservice hosting root folder

this link and schema is helpfull
http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html

http://78.189.../crossdomain.xml this url webservice host root folder.

Comment: Thought that's what I said. AS for being in the root, no it doesn't have to be but you have to explicitly tell your app where it is. The main thing is the domains